# Log of everything VoiceOver is saying

Tags: accessibility, voiceover

Im using VoiceOver during development to test accessibility changes.

Many times VoiceOver detects changes properly, starts reading them, but is interrupted with new information. So the information that is important is essentially cancelled when additional changes present themselves.

In my case I have an alert that's very important, but ancestor changes seem to get read instead.

If I could see a log of everything VoiceOver is saying I can at least be confident the text is being read and figure out a way to mitigate the problem (possibly by delaying it)

Is there anyway to get a Voiceover log?

Comment: Have you tried recording the screen? Sort of like game footage, you can review it later to see where and what is happening.

Comment: Unfortunately most of the time it happens so fast the text doesn't even show in the overlay

Comment: Perhaps slow down the speaking pace. If it is the audio you want then that can help. I cannot speak to how the VO overlay works, but I assume it also goes off the speaking speed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any way to print out a log, but you can save the output to an audio file by pressing `ctrl-option-shift-Z`. If the audio is running too quickly you could try slowing it down or using some commands to repeat the output. Some of the commands listed here might be helpful:
http://lab.dotjay.co.uk/notes/voiceover-commands/